# how to store the output of awk command,which is taken input from pipe into an array using shell scripting program

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to take the input from pipe and store a specified column of the input into an array using awk command. Iam working in UNIX sh environment

```sh
CMD=$1 #command which i am passing as an input.
C=$2  #column number which i want to store in array
array=
/usr/sbin/clido $CMD 2> /dev/null | awk "{array[NR]=\$$C}"
```

and also tried the below command

```sh
/bin/clido $CMD 2> /dev/null | array=( $( awk -v i="$C" '{print $3}' ) )
```

output is nothing storing in the array...it prints an empty array.

Comment: if you pass any command in the command line argument it will execute that command and gives as output.      example my file name is sample.sh,then i should execute the code as (   ./sample.sh "ls -l"  3   ). here i want to execute ls -l command and store the 3 column of that output into array

Answer (score 0):

The first solution does not make sense, because you are setting the `awk` variable named `array`, not the bash variable of that name.

The problem with the second solution is, that you set the `bash` variable `array` inside a pipe. Compare it to this program:

```
echo abc | x=( $(cat) )
```

Here too, x will be empty. The receiving end of the pipe is a child process and x will be set in this child process.

To achieve your goal, use

```
array=( $(/bin/clido $CMD 2> /dev/null | awk -v i="$C" '{print $3}') )
```

Comment: Thank you somuch.. But still I am facing the same problem.. nothing is storing in array.                                                                                                                          $ ls -l
total 340
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   337872 Jul  7 00:02 configTool.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sysmnt sysmnt    113 Jul 11 06:48 sample.sh
drwxrwxr-x. 5 sysmnt sysmnt   4096 Jul  2 11:40 scripts
[sysmnt@SN0101 ~]$                                                                                                        
[sysmnt@SN0101 ~]$ ./sample.sh "ls -l" 3

[sysmnt@SN0101 ~]$

Comment: And if you run just the `clido ... | awk ...` command, do you get something on stdout? If yes, run it under `set -x` and paste the output here.